# How to find out about unused dependencies Maven in Intellij Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, dependencies, pom.xml

My project is growing but i have many unused dependencies, how to find out, which one i really need, and which one is really useless? There is a some Intellij Idea Extensions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can run the Maven goal `dependency:analyze` which lists the dependencies that are not used in your source code. Beware, though, that sometimes dependencies are necessary although they are not referenced in source code.

Comment: Remember to make sure it doesnt fail the build. There is a setting for this.

Comment: @vikingsteve If you want to add a goal to the build, use `dependency:analyze-only ` instead (and configure it appropriately).

Answer (score 3):

Add this plugin to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Then just run `mvn dependency:analyze-report`.